# How to extract genotypes from public 1000G bigquery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to extract GENOTYPE information from [bigquery-public-data:human_genome_variants.1000_genomes_phase_3_optimized_schema_variants_20150220](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:human_genome_variants.1000_genomes_phase_3_optimized_schema_variants_20150220) by SQL.

Considering how the data is organized in the table I find it to be a difficult task. I've used SQL occasionally but not for complex queries. I would be grateful for some guidance.

For this task the relevant columns are:

- names (SNPid)
- reference_bases
- hom_ref_call (sample names that are homozygous 
  to reference bases. therefore each sample has genotype
  'reference_bases'+'reference_bases').

By running the query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(names, '') as SNP, 
       samples, 
       CONCAT(reference_bases, reference_bases) as GT
FROM `bigquery-public-data.human_genome_variants.1000_genomes_phase_3_optimized_schema_variants_20150220`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hom_ref_call) as samples
```

I get:

```
+-----+------------+---------+----+
| Row |    SNP     | samples | GT |
+-----+------------+---------+----+
|   1 | rs10158087 | HG00096 | GG |
|   2 | rs10158087 | HG00097 | GG |
|   3 | rs10465663 | HG00096 | CC |
|   4 | rs10465663 | HG00097 | CC |
+-----+------------+---------+----+
```

The result I am looking for should look like this:

```
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
| Row |    SNP     | HG00096 | HG00097 |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
|   1 | rs10158087 | GG      | GG      |
|   2 | rs10465663 | CC      | CC      |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+
```

**How should I structure the query to get the desired table? Thanks.**

*Note: There are 3500 samples so the column names (HG00096,...) should be generated automatically.*

Answer (score 0):

For your sample, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(names, '') as SNP, 
       samples, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN samples = 'HG00096' THEN reference_bases END) as HG00096,
       MAX(CASE WHEN samples = 'HG00097' THEN reference_bases END) as HG00097
FROM `bigquery-public-data.human_genome_variants.1000_genomes_phase_3_optimized_schema_variants_20150220` CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(hom_ref_call) as samples
GROUP BY SNP;
```

Do note that you need to know the columns that you want in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The problem is that there are 3500 columns. Is there a way to create them automatically?

Comment: @IgorM . . . You can generate the code in Google sheets.  Or perhaps a JSON representation would suffice.